# Update ‘x’ and ‘y’ values of a trace using Plotly.update()

Tags: javascript, plotly, plotly.js

Is it possible to update the `x` and `y` properties of a trace using [`Plotly.update()`](https://plot.ly/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyupdate)?

Updating the `marker.color` property of the trace works well. But when I try updating the `x` or `y` properties the trace disappears from the graph. And there is no indication that something went wrong in the console. I would like to update the values *by trace index* and the update function looks like the right tool.

There may be a clue in the documentation for [`Plotly.react()`](https://plot.ly/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/#plotlyreact):

> Important Note: In order to use this method to plot new items in arrays under  `data`  such as  `x`  or  `marker.color`  etc, these items must either have been added immutably (i.e. the identity of the parent array must have changed) or the value of [`layout.datarevision`](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#layout-datarevision) must have changed.

Though this may the complete unrelated because I *am* able to update `marker.color` using `Plotly.update()` without bumping the `layout.datarevision`.

### Running example:

(codepen example [here](https://codepen.io/jjengland/pen/BaNrKye))

```js
let myPlot = document.getElementById("graph");

let trace = {
  type: 'scatter',
  x: [0.5 * 255],
  y: [0.5 * 255],
  hoverinfo: "skip",
  mode: 'markers',
  marker: {color: "DarkSlateGrey", size: 20},
};

let layout = {
  title: "The Worm Hole",
  yaxis: { range: [0, 255] },
  xaxis: { range: [0, 255] },
};

let config = {responsive: true};

Plotly.newPlot(myPlot, [trace], layout, config);

function updateGraphPoint(cmd) {
  let x = Math.random() * 255;
  let y = Math.random() * 255;
  let z = Math.random() * 255;
  let update = null;
  if (cmd === "color") {
    update = {'marker.color': `rgb(${x}, ${y}, ${z})`};
  } else if (cmd === "position") {
    update = {'x': [x], 'y': [y]};
  }
  Plotly.update(myPlot, update, {}, [0]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="updateGraphPoint('color')">Change my color!</button>
<button onclick="updateGraphPoint('position')">Change my position!</button>
<div id="graph"></div>
```

**Note:** I also [asked this question on the the plotly community forum](https://community.plot.ly/t/update-x-and-y-values-of-a-trace-using-plotly-update/36149) but have not gotten any responses. Maybe someone here knows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data update object accepts an array containing an array of new x / y values for each trace you want to update. I.e. if you only want to update one trace, you still have to provide an array containing an array for that one trace:
`update = {'x': [[x]], 'y': [[y]]};`

```js
let myPlot = document.getElementById("graph");

let trace = {
  type: 'scatter',
  x: [0.5 * 255],
  y: [0.5 * 255],
  hoverinfo: "skip",
  mode: 'markers',
  marker: {color: "DarkSlateGrey", size: 20},
};

let layout = {
  title: "The Worm Hole",
  yaxis: { range: [0, 255] },
  xaxis: { range: [0, 255] },
};

let config = {responsive: true};

Plotly.newPlot(myPlot, [trace], layout, config);

function updateGraphPoint(cmd) {
  let x = Math.random() * 255;
  let y = Math.random() * 255;
  let z = Math.random() * 255;
  let update = null;
  if (cmd === "color") {
    update = {'marker.color': `rgb(${x}, ${y}, ${z})`};
  } else if (cmd === "position") {
    update = {'x': [[x]], 'y': [[y]]};
  }
  Plotly.update(myPlot, update, {}, [0]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="updateGraphPoint('color')">Change my color!</button>
<button onclick="updateGraphPoint('position')">Change my position!</button>
<div id="graph"></div>
```

Comment: what if you want to update traces with array of length 2? Eg:
x: [ 2022-01-01, 2022-02-01],
        y: [Summer, Summer],